# ^How to parse multiple JSON arrays received from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my Json Data received from Server:

```
[
     {"Name":"A"}, 
     {"Name":"B"},
     {"Name":"C"},
     {"Name":null}
]
[
     {"Name":null},
     {"Name":"D"},
     {"Name":null}
]
[ 
     {...},
     {...}
]
```

How do I parse it using using JQUERY in AJAX success attribute?

Here is my Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: '#.php',
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var str = JSON.stringify(data);
        var obj = JSON.parse(str);

        for(var i=0; i< data.length;i++)
        {
            alert(data[i].Name);
        }
    },
    complete: function(xhr,status){
        alert(status);
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        alert("An error occured. Please Try Again");
    }
})
```

This code is not working and giving parser error on complete.
I want to Display all the Names received.
Please Help.

Comment: alert(data[i].Name); is this right or it should be alert(obj[i].Name)?

Comment: That's because your json is invalid. You need to send a valid json format. Also, on a sidenote, theres no point stringifying and then parsing the data, because it's already parsed json.

Comment: You can't return multiple arrays in JSON. As @SebastianNette says, the format of the returned string is invalid.

Comment: @KDP: I don't know about it, hence the question!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Can the returned string only contain one array? like [ { }, { }, ....] ?

Comment: @KaushalShah That's correct.

Comment: @SebastianNette: Thanks for the sidenote!. Can you tell me how do I change the format of JSON response since it is directly coming from mysql query response?

Comment: check if your json is valid here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: How is the json generated?

Comment: while($row1=mysqli_fetch_row($result1) )
  {
  $json1[] = array("Name"=>$row1[0]); 
  }
  echo json_encode($json1);
where result1 is the result of mysql query

Comment: Pack it together then. echo json_encode(array($json1, $json2, $json3)); then data[0] is $json1, data[1] is $json2, etc.

Comment: Nope. I don't have json1, json2 ,etc.
I am dynamically firing mysql queries which have the repsonses in $json1

Comment: I thought you had multiple json, given the json in the above example. Okay, then there must be an other issue. Can you console.log(data); ?

Comment: Well I did some debugging and simply shifted my echo statement to the end of the file and now I am getting the proper Json format response!

Answer (score 2):

your data received from the server are not valid JSON, if it was, it would be 
 something like :

```
[
    [{
        "Name": "A"
    }, {
        "Name": "B"
    }, {
        "Name": "C"
    }, {
        "Name": null
    }],
    [{
        "Name": null
    }, {
        "Name": "D"
    }, {
        "Name": null
    }]
]
```

that would be even easier to parse:

```
[{
    "Name": "A"
}, {
    "Name": "B"
}, {
    "Name": "C"
}, {
    "Name": null
}, {
    "Name": null
}, {
    "Name": "D"
}, {
    "Name": null
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The data returned by your server does not respect JSON syntax.
In order to have a proper JSON structure, there should be only one parent object and not multiple arrays.

If you can modify your server's output, consider the following alternatives:

**Creating a parent array:**

```
[ your_arrays ]
```

then access to `data[0]` to retrieve your arrays  in your `success` function.

**Creating a parent object:**

```
{myArrays : your_arrays}
```

then access to `data.myArrays` in your `success` function.